# AWS Eventbridge: Pattern to capture ALL events

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless, serverless-architecture, amazon-cloudwatch-events

I'd like to deploy an AWS Event Rule in Eventbridge which is triggered by all events, with no filtering whatsoever.

I've tried the following patterns with no luck.

```
{
source: ["*"]
}
```

According to the documentation you cannot leave the pattern empty. Also, any fields not included in the pattern are wildcarded meaning they can be any value.

I've read articles saying Eventbridge can replace services such as SNS and SQS but without these finer controls I don't see that happening.

Thanks

Comment: What about `"source": [{"prefix": "" }]`?

Comment: I'll try this one! Looks promising!

Comment: @Marcin, an empty source prefix using the content filters worked. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear. I will make an answer if you don't mind for future reference.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The **solution** was to use empty [prefix](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/content-filtering-with-event-patterns.html#filtering-prefix-matching) to match all events:

```
{
  "source": [{
    "prefix": ""
  }]
}
```

Comment: This JSON as is did not work for me, but this JSON did:

`{"source": [{"prefix": ""}]}`

Comment: @SunnyPatel Thanks. I see missing quotes. I will update the answer.

Comment: @Marcin, Is there away to make it work with CDK? In CDK, `resource` is `string[]`. So this won't work because `{prefix: string} is not assignable to type string`

Comment: @chepukha If you look at the version 0 answer from Tim Bray seems to work well for CDK.

Answer (score 6):

For CDK in TypeScript you can provide a match pattern using `as any[]`:

```js
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';

const catchAllRule = new cdk.aws_events.Rule(stack, 'CatchAllRule', {
    targets: [...],
    eventBus: ...,
    eventPattern: {
        source: [ { prefix: ''} ] as any[]
    }
});
```

Generates this CloudFormation:

```yaml
  EventId:
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties:
      EventBusName:
        Ref: ...
      EventPattern:
        source:
          - prefix: ""
      State: ENABLED
```

This works in TypeScript. In other languages you may have to use escape hatch and override the property.

References:

- Escape hatch: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cfn_layer.html
- CfnRule: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_events.CfnRule.html
- Event patterns: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-event-patterns.html

Relevant issues:

- https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/6184
- https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/20486

Answer (score 3):

My favorite was { "version": ["0"] }

Comment: Won't that one day be false for some events?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `exists` filter: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/content-filtering-with-event-patterns.html#filtering-exists-matching

One caveat of using this is that it's not working properly when defined in CloudFormation, but at least it works in SDK and in console.

Answer (score 0):

Using serverless framework you can use the following event pattern to receive ALL events from the bus `eventBusName` for your account with ID `accountID`:

```
  - eventBridge:
      eventBus: arn:aws:events:${aws:region}:${aws:accountId}:event-bus/eventBusName
      pattern:
        account: ["accountID"]
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that is looking for the **CDK-Python** version, it can be achieved with:

```
event_pattern=aws_events.EventPattern(
    source=aws_events.Match.prefix(""),  # Do not filter anything
)
```

This follows the `prefix` approach explained in this response (https://stackoverflow.com/a/62407802/13957271).