# AWS configure cloud watch/trail to monitor for 'AccessDenied' and 'UnauthorizedOperation' errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudtrail

I'd like to setup some monitoring for capturing access denied and unauthorized operation errors in my AWS account. I'd like to capture all of these events across different AWS services but have run into some issues. I've initially setup some a couple of cloud watch rules that trigger a basic lambda function but I'm not capturing the events I'm looking for. Below are a couple of the rules events that trigger a Lambda function (ideally I'd filter these down from capturing all events once I get this working).

```
{
  "source": ["aws.cloudtrail"],
  "detail-type": ["AWS API Call via CloudTrail"],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": ["cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"]
  }
}
// All cloud watch
{
  "source": [
    "aws.cloudwatch"
  ]
 }
```

I've been testing with the AWS CLI, making calls to resources I don't have access too e.g. :

- aws dynamodb list-tables
- aws ec2 describe-instances
- List item

I'm getting the correct errors in response from the CLI but I'm not seeing these events being propagated to the Lambda (I am seeing other non errors triggering the Lambda though).

Do I have to configure this more narrowly or am I missing a step for collecting these errors?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`aws dynamodb list-tables`, `aws ec2 describe-instances` and `List item` do not work because `List*`,  `Get*` and `Describe*` API events are **not supported** by CloudWatch Events:

[image]

If you want to capture such events, you have to **do it through CloudWatch Logs**. Namely, setup your [CT trail to push events to CloudWatch Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/send-cloudtrail-events-to-cloudwatch-logs.html). Then, setup a [subscription filter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html#LambdaFunctionExample) to your lambda. This will push all API events to your lambda through CloudWatch Logs. Subsequently, you will be able to detect `AccessDenied` errors in the events and perform other actions you require.

Other possibility would be to setup [metric filter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/MonitoringLogData.html) on the logs so that `AccessDenied` errors are captured to create a CloudWatch metric. Then you setup a CloudWatch Alarm based on the metric. This will trigger an alarm, but it will not pass the details of event that triggered the alarm to your function. You will only know that access denied happened, but without further details.

**Update**

`create-table` works as expected. I used the following rule in my tests which I hooked up to SQS for quick checks:

```
{
  "detail-type": [
    "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": [
      "dynamodb.amazonaws.com"
    ],
    "errorCode": [
      "AccessDenied"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response @Marcin! I didn't realize that constraint with Cloudwatch events. I did try using another api call 'aws dynamodb create-table' and had similar results though, I'm leaning towards there is likely something wrong with my setup. Do you know if there are any other restrictions or if a 'create' doesn't qualify as a 'write' API call?

Comment: @MattLock No problem. I updated the answer. create table works with events.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Marcin, I'm going to accept the answer / reward the bounty. If I wanted to make that more broad and catch all cloud trail AccessDenieds, could I replace the event source with '"eventSource": ["cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"]' ?

Comment: @MattLock Thanks. This would only limit your rule to cloudtrial API events, not other services. To apply it to all services you can try removing `eventSource` all together. But I haven't tested it.

Comment: Incase you were interested, removing the eventSource didn't work unfortunately

Comment: @MattLock Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62406933/aws-eventbridge-pattern-to-capture-all-events/62407802#62407802) will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I wasn't able to set that as a CloudWatch rule as the syntax in that post was 'invalid' but I was able to set the source as an EventBridge rule. I didn't realize there was a difference between what type of filtering you could do on both services.